# Invisible Foxpro views in linked server

Tags: linked-server, foxpro, visual-foxpro

We have a foxpro application that is still in use. I am creating new user interfaces to the data as a first step to trying to migrate away from foxpro. We don't have the code for the GUI--I can get at the tables and views in the VFP IDE.

I can access the data externally using a linked server in Sql Server 2005 or datasets in Visual Studio 2010. I can see all the Foxpro tables in but not the views.

Is there any way to see and use the views in the linked server or dataset?

Answer (score 1):

If the views are built into the database container (i.e. local views) you can see them by opening the database via the command window 'open database (name)', 'modify database' you can then see the views and just copy the sql statement and create the same thing in your new app. I don't think you can directly call the views, but I could be wrong.  I haven't used built in views in several years now, it's all mostly SQL select statements that are easily used in other languages.

Or in the VFP ide add the database to a project and then view and grab the code from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering and suggestions. I was hoping there was some setting I was missing, not being very fluent with the VFP IDE.